# Need to filter a list with 10+ criteria

Tags: list, filter, data-view-web-part

Need to create a list filter with over 10 criteria. Research tells me that it can be done with a Data View web part but I have not found any instructions on how this is done.

Comment: Hi. What do you mean with "over 10 criteria"?

Comment: @jpussacq, Filter conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SharePoint designer app to create more than 10 criteria for your filters. You will need to know some CAML to be able to achieve this, but thankfully it is reasonably easy to learn. [MSDN CAML for Queires](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467521.aspx) is a good starting point for understanding how to use CAML for filters.

I would recommend you build up your initial filter criteria in the web browser as normal, then open your view in the SharePoint designer. It will open as an .ASPX page, which will allow you to manually add CAML. You will see a line which starts with the following:

```
<View Name="....
```

If you scroll over on that line you should eventually see the `<Query>` tag. Inside of this tag is all your currently create criteria, you can add more to this list and save the file. It will then get uploaded to the server and you should see the filter take effect.

A complete sample query would look something like this:

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text">Some Value</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

Using the link provided earlier, and the auto-generated CAML code you should be able to extend and construct much larger and more complicated queries.

Comment: Thanks! There is also a CAML Query builder tool: http://www.u2u.be/Software

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated column to sumarize criteria and then filter with this new column.

Perhaps you need to create one or two calculated column.

You do need code or sharepoint designer for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your list view web part, in the filter section, select your column on which you want to filter, apply the condition of Greater Than and save the filter.

Here is a nice tutorial to do this kind of filtration.

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/08/11/understanding-filters-in-sharepoint-list-views-aspx/

Or you can also try the below link.

http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/sharepoint-2013-list-view-filtering-with-query-string-21176.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I recently found another much simpler way to do this.

Simply modify the view's filtering and sorting using the column header drop downs, and then click the Save This View link. It does allow you to select more than 10 filter options, and the Save This View saves them!

[image]