# Only show users filled in values in a Choice field

Tags: 2010, list-view, filter

I have several libraries, containing each a Choice column with several standard values. To each value there is a view which filters on the particular value.

The users can also specify there own value.

Now I want all values that are specified by the users them selfs to appear in an Other view. Is there any simple way to configure this view or will I have to create a "column" is not equal to "Value" for each choice value that should not be shown in the view?

I really hope there is a simple non code solution for this, because we are talking a lot of libraries :-)

regards 
Maria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case SharePoint Designer is not an option, a calculated column can be used to achieve this. The formula in the calculated column determines the filter that would be used by the view.

**Example**

Create a calculated column `PriorityView` and use Choice column `Priority`. Example formula `=IF(Priority="High",Priority,IF(Priority="Normal",Priority,IF(Priority="Medium",Priority,"Other")))`

[image]

Then make views based on the calculated column value.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

if you want to view the data like it is in a standard view of SharePoint, you have unfortunately no other possibility as to filter every single value with "not equal". Be aware that you are only able to use up to 10 filters each view.

Here you can read about a CAML method involving the use of SHarePoint designer:
[Need to filter a list with 10+ criteria](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176944/need-to-filter-a-list-with-10-criteria)