# Can I add more than 10 filters to a SharePoint view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, administration, filter

Am I capable of increasing the maximum number of filters available in a view?

It seems to cap out at 10, and I haven't found anything in the documentation about how many filters you can add:

[image]

Comment: Try few of the workarounds given here and let me know if those works for you: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176944/need-to-filter-a-list-with-10-criteria

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to add more than 10 filters from "list view settings" page in SharePoint.

However, you can try below steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint online list view
2. Apply filters based on your list columns using "Filter by" option available on column headers, like:

   [image]
3. After applying all the required filters (more than 10), click on "Switch view options" drop down and select **Save view as**:

   [image]
4. DO NOT change name of view on the popup and just click **Save**:

   [image]
5. It should save all your filters without any issue.

I have saved list view with 12 column filters and it worked fine for me:

[image]

**Note**: Do not make any changes from classic "list view settings" page after applying filters from modern list view as it might overwrite the filters and limit it to maximum 10 filters.

Few other workarounds can be found at: [Need to filter a list with 10+ criteria](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176944/need-to-filter-a-list-with-10-criteria)